# Connecting to AWS EC2 with terraform and execute commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm new to infrastructure.
I'm trying to create an EC2 instance and execute commands using Terraform provisioners. However, when I apply the Terraform configuration, it times out.

```bash
$ ssh_keygen -f ./example -m PEM // this generate example.pub and example
```

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "example" {
  key_name   = "keypair"
  public_key = file("./example.pub")
  tags = {
    Name = "Example Key Pair"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-003634241a8fcdec0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.example.key_name
  tags = {
    Name = "Example EC2"
  }

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = self.public_ip
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("./example")
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    content     = "Hello World!"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/example.txt"
  }

}
```

Comment: Is the instance in the default or a custom VPC? Is your Security Group configured to allow port 22? Are you assigning a public IP address to the instance? Does your VPC have an IGW defined? There are many details lacking from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please add the following:

```
provisioner "file" {
source      = "example.txt"              # terraform machine
destination = "/home/ubuntu/example.txt" # remote machine
}
```

before:

```
provisioner "file" {
    content     = "Hello World!"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/example.txt"
  }
```

where "example.txt" is an empty file available on your Terraform machine?

Does it hangs as well?

Comment: Thanx. I tried this code. but it still times out

Comment: Please, check the NSG!

Comment: You could try to temporarily remove the provisioner blocks verifying if you are able to access to the instances via ssh.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found out that the issue was caused by the security group. To simplify the code, I omitted some parts and used the default security group, but I forgot to open port 22 on the default security group.

Comment: Happy to have been helpful!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The direct problem here was (based on comments on the other answer) an incorrect security group configuration, which is a common cause of problems with provisioners and one of the reasons why [Provisioners are a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort).

This seems to be an example of [Passing data into virtual machines and other compute resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources), in which case the documentation recommends against using provisioners and instead using the `user_data` or `user_data_base64` arguments of `aws_instance`, which will pass data to the EC2 instance indirectly through the EC2 API, rather than directly over SSH. That avoids the need for any direct network connectivity between Terraform and the EC2 instance, so incorrect security group rules cannot prevent it from working.

Exactly how to use that will depend on what software is installed in the AMI you have chosen here, but most standard Linux distribution AMIs use the software [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle system configuration tasks such as handling the `user_data` argument. If you are using an AMI which has cloud-init installed then the following official tutorial shows how to use it:

> ### [Provision Infrastructure with Cloud-Init](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/provision/cloud-init)
>
> When you create a generic compute resource in Terraform, your virtual machine (VM) may not have much capability because it is a "fresh" install and needs to be provisioned with the software you want to use. Manually installing the necessary software and its respective dependencies on each VM is time consuming and difficult to maintain at scale.
>
> `cloud-init` is a standard configuration support tool available on most Linux distributions and all major cloud providers. `cloud-init` allows you to pass a shell script to your instance that installs or configures the machine to your specifications.
>
> In this tutorial, you will create a Terraform instance with the `user_data` to deploy a Go web app and SSH key to the newly created device, allowing you to SSH into the machine without a password and start the app with that user.
>
> [Read more...](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/provision/cloud-init)